# Bluesnap Onsite Payment wtih subscriptions

Tags: php, payment-gateway, bluesnap

I have worked on Bluesnap on-site payment, payment has been done successfully, but i didn't get the product name in order locater, also didn't get the option of subscriptions in order detail.

Is there any way to make transaction via on-site with subscription/recurring?

API Reference
http://docs.bluesnap.com/ExtendedPaymentAPI/Default.htm#ClientSideEncryption/Web.htm

Answer (score 3):

Subscriptions in the API are no longer in the development phase. They're in the documentation already. They are available [here](http://developers.bluesnap.com/v2.0/docs/create-plan).

Answer (score 1):

once you are loggedin the console you need to setup the contract as standard subscription - there is a documentation [here](https://support.bluesnap.com/docs/subscription-billing-setup) that provides step by step on how to do it.

once the contract is setup correctly(as a subscription type) under a product; you can basically purchase using the contact(through Buy Now or APIs) to start the subscription.

Comment: did you have any demo or any implementation of on-site ?

Comment: @Awais: did you check the link in the answer above?

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I have made a successful transactions, and i got the transactions in order locater, but didn't get the product name in order locater detail....

Comment: Awais: Product name is right in the order  locator page - see image => http://imgur.com/AzvDvdw

Comment: its in following format **(Productname) - (productId) - (Contract Name) - (ContractId)**

Comment: @Awais : any luck?

Comment: Narayan, not yet, because according to bluesnap support team, API is under development phase, so we have decided to move on stripe payment gateway...

Answer (score 1):

BlueSnap supports subscriptions via their Payment API. You can create custom billing plans, define a trial period and/or initial charge, set your billing frequency, and so on. BlueSnap’s Subscription Billing Engine will then automatically process your recurring subscription payments, keep your shoppers' cards updated, and run automatic retries for subscription payments during your grace period.

To see how to Create a Plan, [go here](http://developers.bluesnap.com/v2.0/docs/create-plan).

To see how to Create a Subscription, [go here](http://developers.bluesnap.com/v2.0/docs/create-plan).